# jQuery mobile multiple events like keyup/keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, multi-touch

I am currently developing an html5 game for both mobile and non-mobile.

The way the UI works right now for mobile, is that when you hold down on the right side of the screen, the character moves right. Hold down the left end and the character goes left. Tap the middle of the screen to shoot and swipe up to jump. All of these work fine.

However, I would like to have it where while moving right, the user can also tap the screen to shoot, or swipeup to jump. For example, in the non-mobile version, while holding down the right arrow key, if you press the top arrow at the same time you will jump while moving right. The events dont block each other. However, with touch events it seems like you can only fire one at a time. If im holding the right side to run, and then tap, ill stop running. As a matter of fact, I wont shoot either, so it seems like the two events just cancel each other out.

Im not sure if this is a semantic error, or if its not possible, but any suggestions/help would be much appreciated. If it's not possible to do this with jQuery events, perhaps there is some inventive way I could accomplish this with JS or a framework?

Here is the code for the events, if it helps at all:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '#game', function(e) {
                        //x coordinate of touch
                        var touchX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                    `enter code here`    //what part of the canvas are we touching?
                        var leftSide = touchX <= .10 * width; //left 10% of width
                        var rightSide = touchX >= .90 * width; //right 10% of width
                        if (leftSide || rightSide) {
                            //if they are jumping or shooting they cant do anything but jump unless they are in the air
                            if ((player.currentAction !== 'jumping' || (player.currentAction === 'jumping' && (player.y === groundLocation || !noObstacleCollisions(player))))) {
                                var action;
                                if (leftSide) action = 'moving left';
                                else if (rightSide) action = 'moving right';
                                player.action(action);
                                player.lastAction = action;
                                //dont add duplicate actions, since keyup is constantly called when held down
                                if (!inArray(player.currentActions, action)) {
                                    player.currentActions.push(action);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //when tap is released update current actions
                    $(document).on('touchend', '#game', function() {
                        //if we're moving left or right stop when we let go of the key
                        //also make sure we're either on the ground or on a platform when we do that
                        //we dont want to break midair trajectory
                        var movingLeftOrRight = player.vx !== 0;
                        if (movingLeftOrRight && (!noObstacleCollisions(player) || player.y === groundLocation)) {
                            player.action('standing'); //stop player
                        }
                        //remove action associated with key
                        if (player.vx > 0) removeFromArray(player.currentActions, 'moving right');
                        if (player.vx < 0) removeFromArray(player.currentActions, 'moving left');
                        if (movingLeftOrRight) player.lastAction = null;
                    });
                    //jump up when swiping up
                    $(document).on('swipeup', '#game', function() {
                        if ((player.currentAction !== 'jumping' || (player.currentAction === 'jumping' && (player.y === groundLocation || !noObstacleCollisions(player)))))
                            player.action('jumping');
                    });
                    //fire on middle screen tap (not touchstart to not conflict with jumping)
                    $(document).on('tap', '#game', function(e) {
                        var leftSide = e.pageX <= .10 * width; //left 10% of width
                        var rightSide = e.pageX >= .90 * width; //right 10% of width
                        if (!(leftSide || rightSide)) {
                            player.action('shooting');
                        }
                    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll need a javascript library for multi-touch gestures. It worth looking http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ - hammer.js